# On key up event working only once in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a JavaScript game. There, I have created a function that whenever we press the right arrow key, the DIV should move to the right. When I press it for the first time, it works fine. However, when I press it after that, it does not work. Here is the code I have tried so far:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .runobj {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #00ff00;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onkeydown="moveObj(event)">
  <div class="runobj" id="runobj"></div>
  <script>
    function moveObj(event) {
      var runobj = document.getElementById("runobj");
      if (event.keyCode === 37) {
        runobj.style.left -= 10;
      } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
        runobj.style.left += 10;
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: `style.left` is a string property. You need to use either `offsetLeft` or `parseFloat(style.left)`. Also when setting the property you shall not forget the unit, like `px`. So together it would be `runobj.style.left = parseFloat(runobj.style.left) - 10 + 'px';`

Comment: You should put `var runobj = ...` out of the function, so you select it once from the DOM, instead of every time a key is pressed. Also, this is a good place for a `switch` statement, instead of `if...else if... else if... else if...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified your code to handle the postfix `px` for `left` attribute:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .runobj {
      width: 80px;
      height: 80px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #00ff00;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onkeydown="moveObj(event)">
  <div class="runobj" id="runobj"></div>
  <script>
  var _left = 0;
    function moveObj(event) {
      var runobj = document.getElementById("runobj");
      if (event.keyCode === 37) {
        _left -= 10;
      } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
        _left += 10;
      }
      runobj.style.left = _left + 'px';
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This way presents a small disadvantage in having to maintain the initial left twice and being bound to the unit `px`.

Comment: @JavaScript, I agree, However, I didn't work on enhancing the whole code, just tried to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`style.left` is a string property with a unit (ie: **"10px"**). To add or take units of it you first need to parse it to a number or use another property (ie: `offsetLeft`) and after assign it back with the unit.

```js
function moveObj(element, event){
  console.log('keycode', event.keyCode);

  //REM: Looking up the same element all the time is not ideal. Maybe pass it instead?
  var runobj = element || document.getElementById("runobj");
  
  //REM: You need to turn "style.left" into a number
  var tCurrentLeft = parseFloat(runobj.style.left) || 0;

  //REM: Just use a switch, since it looks like you are going to implement more key actions
  switch(event.keyCode){
    case 37:
      //REM: Do not forget to add the unit
      runobj.style.left = tCurrentLeft - 10 + 'px';
      break
    case 39:
      //REM: Do not forget to add the unit
      runobj.style.left = tCurrentLeft + 10 + 'px'
  };
  
  console.log('left', runobj.style.left)
};

//REM: It is better to fully split the javascript from the HTML markup. Also you can just pass the element and avoid lookups.
window.addEventListener('keydown', moveObj.bind(this, document.getElementById("runobj")));
```

```css
.runobj {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #00ff00;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="runobj" id="runobj"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the function recursive so that on every click event it should moved automatically without refreshing it to the initials .

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

After the first modification, the value of the left property is the string '10px'. So to continue adding values, you need to extract that value before adding a new values, for example:

```
runobj.style.left = parseInt(runobj.style.left || 0, 10) + 10;
```

(The '|| 0' is for the first iteration, because it receives an empty string)

Comment: TBH I also thought I was required to append 'px' before setting back the numeric value, but it isn't, at least in chrome 84 (ubuntu). But yes, I agree that the correct thing to do is to append the units.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// cache the element
var runobj = document.getElementById("runobj");

function moveObj(event) {
  var left = runobj.getBoundingClientRect().left;

  if (event.keyCode === 37) {
    left -= 10;
  } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
    left += 10;
  }

  runobj.style.left = left + "px";
}
```

[Working example](https://codepen.io/digitalify/pen/mdrBYLV)

Answer (score 0):

We need to convert `style.left` from String datatype to Number datatype inorder to increment or decrement the value.

After the first modification, the value of the left property is the string '10px'.

So when you tried to increment `style.left` by number 10 after the first modification, it becomes `10px10` which is not a valid value for `style.left` property.That's why it only works for the first time.

```
var runobj = document.getElementById("runobj");
function moveObj(event) {

  /* Converting the left style value from String type to Number type.
  '|| 0' is for the first iteration, because it receives an empty string */

  var current = parseFloat(runobj.style.left) || 0;
  
  if (event.keyCode === 37) {
        current += 20;
      } else if (event.keyCode === 39) {
        current -= 20;
      }
      // Updating the value
      runobj.style.left = current;
}
```